Issue Copying Posts and Pages from One WordPress Site to Another
I am currently trying to copy all posts and pages from one WordPress site to another and have encountered an issue I can't resolve. Here’s an outline of what I've done so far:

Export out a backup of a site's data I want to copy over to the new site
Import the data into the new site which has all the plugins set up and ready to go
Change the URL of the posts

However, when I try to create/edit/delete the posts. I cannot do anything.
When I create a new post, I am greeted with this error.
Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7648 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7649 Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7653 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7908 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3644 Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/usage/module.php on line 208 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3870 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5579 Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5579 Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4880 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local::on_save_post() must be an instance of WP_Post, null given, called in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 326 and defined in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/template-library/sources/local.php:1112 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(326): Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local->on_save_post(0, NULL) #1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php(4891): do_action('save_post', 0, NULL, false) #4 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/post.php(766): wp_insert_post(Array, false, false) #5 /var/www/html/wp-admin/post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit('page', true) #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/template-library/sources/local.php on line 1112

